# I want to read the input from a text file and the input is as follows

Tags: java

```
Vijay 11:30 12:30
Jai 12:30 12:50
Vijay 13:45 14:25
Vijay 17:25 17:50
```

I want each line and each input to be inserted in a different array or list
And the date should be in the same format.

Comment: newbie you have to post some code and show us some research efforts first

Comment: Why do you want to create a new list for each line ? does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes actually it is for comparison of two companies whose timing is less for the same service.
That means I have to subtract the time span and show the best time taken to perform or provide the same service.
@Rehman

Comment: Sorry,
Next time I will consider your suggestion.
@singhakash

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file"));
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
String str;
while(null != (str = br.readLine()))
    list.add(str.split(" "));
```

This will give you a list of String arrays which contain the file data.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement this will not be a good approach at all.
You should keep your data in a xml format like :

data.xml

```
<services>
    <service>
        <serviceName>Vijay</serviceName><startTime>11:30</startTime><endTime>12:30</endTime>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceName>John</serviceName><startTime>14:30</startTime>16:30<endTime></endTime>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceName>John</serviceName><startTime>13:30</startTime><endTime>14:30</endTime>
    </service>
</employees>
```

And there should be DTO class e.g Service.java. You have to deserialize that xml to create multiple objects of Service class using JAXB. In this approach you can handle the data in much easier way.

Service.java

```
package test.com;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="service")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Service {

@XmlElement(name="serviceName")
private String serviceName;

@XmlElement(name="startTime")
private String startTime;

@XmlElement(name="endTime")
private String endTime;

public String getServiceName() {
    return serviceName;
}

public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
    this.serviceName = serviceName;
}

public String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public String getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}

public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return serviceName + "  "+startTime+ "  "+endTime;
}
```

}

ServiceList.java

```
package test.com;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "serviceList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ServiceList {

    @XmlElement(name = "service")
    private ArrayList<Service> serviceList;

    public ArrayList<Service> getServiceList() {
        return serviceList;
    }

    public void setServiceList(ArrayList<Service> serviceList) {
        this.serviceList = serviceList;
    }
}
```

TestMain.java

```
public class TestMain  {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ServiceList.class);
        Unmarshaller m = context.createUnmarshaller();
        ServiceList s = (ServiceList)m.unmarshal(new File("D:/data.xml"));
        System.out.println(s.getServiceList().get(0).getServiceName());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```